# Session ID error

Tags: php, html

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 - **This is my error.**

All I am trying to create is a simple show the current logged in user but it wont work for me here is my code:

```
<?php 
        //get the session id
    $session = isset($_SESSION["user_id"]);
        // sql statement to the database to get the username
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_sys_user WHERE USR_ID = ".$session."";
        $result = mysqli_query($db,$query) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($db));;
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
              echo "<p class='white'>".$row['USR_Name']."</p>";
            }

    ?>
```

Comment: `WHERE USR_ID = '".$session."'";` and remember to use `session_start();` if not in there yet.

Comment: What datatype is your `USR_ID` field? If it's anything other than `int` (or another numerical representation) then you need to encapsulate your `WHERE` clause with quotes, as @Fred-ii- has commented.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this:

```
   $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_sys_user WHERE USR_ID = ".$session."";
```

To this:

```
   $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_sys_user WHERE USR_ID = '".$session."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_sys_user WHERE USR_ID = '$session'";
```

and of course use the session_start();

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_sys_user WHERE USR_ID = '".$session."'";
```

But this

```
$session = isset($_SESSION["user_id"]);
```

Don't do, what do you extepted